Detect caps lock in HTML input element
I want to detect CapsLock in an input. I used getModifierState which I found here:


function handle(ev, el) {
  //if (ev.isComposing || ev.keyCode === 229) return;  // for firefox
  let isCapsLockOn = ev.getModifierState('CapsLock');
  document.getElementById('message').innerText = isCapsLockOn ? 'CAPS LOCK' : '.';
  let log = document.getElementById('log');
  log.innerText = new Date() + '\n' + log.innerText;
}
<input onkeydown="handle(event, this)" />
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="log"></div>



When pressing CapsLock in the input, I expect it to show or hide "CAPS LOCK". But what actually happens is it flickers on and off, or shows the message but opposite to whether the key is actually on.
One can also see from the "log" element that the event is firing twice. I don't know why, but that's probably the reason.
I tried in firefox, chromium and edge, with the same result. So I doubt (?) it's a misbehaving browser extension. I'm using a standard qwerty keyboard. For firefox I also added if (ev.isComposing || ev.keyCode === 229) return; as per this.
How can I fix this?
UPDATE
Thanks to the commenters below, it seems like this should work. So in the spirit of the "Works For Me" idea, I guess this one just "Doesn't Work For Me".

I can't reproduce this.

Your code appears to work for me.

So you are concerned by the case of the actual CapsLock key? On my macOS Chrome I have about the inverse of what you describe, with an event firing only once every two strokes (the one setting the caps-lock). I need to add an onkeyup (i.e. I have both listeners) to also catch the other one. https://jsfiddle.net/zv5sf2jL/ On Firefox it works just as expected with only onkeydown. For both, capturing any other key works as expected.

If my demo works for others, then maybe there's something wonky with my browser, or it's a naughty browser extension. I don't understand what it could be. Thanks for double checking it for me.

I cannot reproduce the problem. Have you verified that your keyboard is working ok, or that there is not a background program modifying your keystrokes (autohotkey, etc)?

@AyesC There's nothing of that sort going on. :)

If you are really only concerned about the CapsLock key, maybe add an early exit check if (ev.key !== "CapsLock") { return; }to be sure that the "Works for me" comments are actually testing the same thing as you are.

@Kaiido Thanks for the demo. It works the opposite for me to what you've described. I guess this must be a browser compatibility issue, or browser extension issue. I can't imagine it being anything else, given it works for other people.

Oh, it can be a lot of other things. Different OS, different IMEs, different browsers, maybe even different hardware... But this ought to be working in a standard way, so that's indeed a compat' issue. Unfortunately UI events specs are not the strictest ones currently. But given that we both have different results, I strongly suspect others aren't testing like you and I are. So in your position I'd really make it clear that you are only concerned about stroking multiple time the CapsLock key and not other keys.

@Kaiido Agreed. Thank you for your advice. I'll just live with it I guess. It does seem to work for most people which is good enough I suppose.

It works as its supposed to work if an input is given. E.g if I type lower case letter it shows caps lock off. If I type with caps, it shows caps lock on. But scenario when it does not work is when I don't type any letter and simply press caps lock button on and off. If I understood correctly that's what you are trying to fix?

Could you please clarify what's your expected outcome? Maybe you need to specifically listen to that caps lock press event.

The reason you're seeing the event fired twice is probably because you are listening the keydown event. When you press and hold down the key, the keydown event gets triggered multiple times.
A better solution would be to use the keyup event instead, which fires after the key is pressed and released:
JavaScript
<script>
  function handle(ev, el) {
    let isCapsLockOn = ev.getModifierState('CapsLock');
    document.getElementById('message').innerText = isCapsLockOn ? 'CAPS LOCK' : '.';
    let log = document.getElementById('log');
    log.innerText = new Date() + '\n' + log.innerText;
  }
</script>

HTML
<body>
  <input onkeyup="handle(event, this)" />
  <div id="message" role="alert"></div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</body>

Snippet


    <body>
      <input onkeyup="handle(event, this)" />
      <div id="message" role="alert"></div>
      <div id="log"></div>
    </body>
    
        <script>
      function handle(ev, el) {
        let isCapsLockOn = ev.getModifierState('CapsLock');
        document.getElementById('message').innerText = isCapsLockOn ? 'CAPS LOCK' : '.';
        let log = document.getElementById('log');
        log.innerText = new Date() + '\n' + log.innerText;
      }
    </script>




Thanks. It's not that though, and I tried both handlers separately and together too. Also, your demo also fires twice for me. Firefox.

Update: in chromium it fires only once. Weird.

On my Chrome on macOS this only outputs "." when pressing repeatingly on CapsLock (not maintaining it).

CapsLock doesn't emit a character on which you can test whether it was uppercase or not.

Yes @Kaiido is right, the caplock doesn't emit anything that's why we must check using the getModifierState approach. i think this is a weird browser or browser extension issue. It seems to work in different ways for different people. And that's confusing because it should be standardised and should work on all browsers in the same way. I ran chromium without extensions chromium --disable-extensions and had the same issue. Weird!

Yeah, thanks for reporting it, I tried my best here man, but I can't solve it without getModifierState, because, on theory, it should work for all browsers and OS the same way

you can try this solution


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Caps Lock Detection</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="inputField" placeholder="Type something...">
<div id="capsLockWarning" style="display: none; color: red;">Caps Lock is on!</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("inputField").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    // Check if Caps Lock key is pressed
    var capsLockOn = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState("CapsLock");

    // Check if the pressed key is a letter and is uppercase when Caps Lock is off
    if (event.key && event.key.match(/[a-z]/i) && event.key === event.key.toUpperCase() && !capsLockOn) {
      document.getElementById("capsLockWarning").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("capsLockWarning").style.display = "none";
    }
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>




Thanks for your help. Your demo doesn't work for me though, in any browser.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
